# Where is the default Settings file in a Visual Basic Project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm editing a Visual Basic application. I save some settings per user. I need to know where the application configuration is located in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Either  of below options let you to see the settings file. The important thing about the file is, it shows settings properties and their default values. You can't see user values which is saved by application. Current values for user settings are stored in '%userprofile%\appdata\local' in a folder with the name of your application in a sub folder which is unique for deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the user settings strings, you can see them from the menu:
Project->[YourProject] Properties...
Then select 'Settings' at the side tab.

The project application configuration is under My Project in the Solution explorer, or the project window mentioned above, but the 'Application' tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are in **Settings.settings** file which is by default hidden in a VB.NET project. The file shows settings properties and their default values.

To show it you can:

1. Click on Project node in **Solution Explorer**
2. Click on **Show All Files** button on the toolbar [image]
3. Open **My Project** node
4. Double click on **Settings.settings** to open it in designer

[image]

Alternatively as mentioned also by Jim, you can Right Click on Project node and choose **Properties**, then you can see the settings in **Settings** tab of project properties.